# 16.04 LTS Display Problems: Chromium, Gimp, etc

Tags: display, chromium, gimp, amd-graphics

I am running 16.04 LTS. My motherboard is made by MSI. It uses an AMD 64-bit processor with either a Radeon HD4200 or HD3000 GPU. I will describe the problems I have been having. I wonder whether they might be related to the AMD driver problem. Here are the problems:

1. Gnome System Monitor runs but does not show up on screen.
2. Chromium browser runs, but nothing shows on screen
3. I can use Firefox for browsing, but

   ```
   firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote
   firefox -ProfileManager
   firefox -P
   ```

   all cause Firefox to start but not to display on screen.
4. Gimp 2.8 runs but does not produce a display.

Thunderbird and several apps work fine.
Might this be the AMD driver problem?
If not, any suggestions as to what the problem is?

Comment: Please provide the exact GPU model and driver version you are using.

Comment: Does this help? Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)? If not, please tell me how to find the info. BTW, the problem has gone away. I have two monitors, one VGA and one DVI. The initial 16.04 'Display' screen showed themas both 'on' even though the VGA monitor was turned off electrically. When I turned off the VGA monitor in the 'Dsiplay' window, things worked.